# eclipse, javascript and @memberof

Tags: javascript, eclipse, requirejs, jsdoc

I'm currently discovering the javascript support in eclipse. One of the things I'm surprised / puzzled about is the outline management.

I've read online (understand "stackoverflow" of course ;) ) that I should put @memberof annotations on the methods.

So here I start:

```
/**
 * @class CustomCanvas
 */
define([], function () {
    var draw;

    /**
     * @method draw
     * @memberOf CustomCanvas
     */
    draw = function () { ... };
});
```

And... it doesn't work. My outline stays empty.

But if I move the @memberof annotation to the class documentation, it works fine:

```
/**
 * @class CustomCanvas
 * @memberOf CustomCanvas
 */
define([], function () {
    var draw;

    /**
     * @method draw
     */
    draw = function () { ... };
});
```

So what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Is that `define` call meant to define a module in an AMD environment (like RequireJS)?

Comment: Yes, requirejs, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to have modules in your documentation (for whatever reason) you can do:

```
define(/** @lends global */function () {

/**
 * @class
 */
function CustomCanvas() {
}

/**
 * Draws something...
 */
CustomCanvas.prototype.draw  = function () {
};

return CustomCanvas;

});
```

If you want it to be in a module in the documentation:

```
/**
 * @module foo
 */
define(/** @lends module:foo */ function () {

/**
 * @class
 */
function CustomCanvas() {
}

/**
 * Draws something...
 */
CustomCanvas.prototype.draw  = function () {
};

return CustomCanvas;

});
```

I've run both snippets through jsdoc 3.2.2 to make sure they work.